# Emmet in PHPStorm 8 EAP for blade.php files

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble to use emmet (zen coding) in my *.blade.php files using PHPStorm 8.

It works fine in *.php files and *.html files but it doesn't work at all in my .blade.php files. So my question is do I need to add that extension somewhere in any emmet settings? I've been searching around and watching the settings without any good answer.

So do anyone have any clue? And why not hint with more PHPStorm plugins which will help improve PHPStorm to be a better Laravel editor just shout it out please.

**EDIT:**
I just found out that the problem seems to be the file type association. Now I've got it associated with the "Files supported via TextMate bundles" and that seems to break the emmet support. If I change that to "*.blade.php" to be associated with .html it works. But now I lose the blade syntax highlighting, does anyone know if it's possible to fix?

Comment: No other way. Wait until [proper Blade support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14172) will be implemented for PhpStorm (planned for v8 .. so could be in any of the future EAP builds)

Comment: Any updates due to this Problem?

Comment: If I remember it right I had to compromise and go back to lose my syntax highlighting since I found the emmet be more necessary to me. But I think PHPStorm is very soon ready for blade support if it isn't already by default.

Comment: its now available in phpstorm btw